# Парсить и показывать только указанное количество новостей из RSS-ленты

Tags: php, парсер, rss

Есть вот такой код, который выводит новостей из RSS-ленты:

```
<?php
    $feed = "/rss/news/feed.rss";
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
    foreach ($sxml->attributes() as $key => $value) {
    }
    foreach ($sxml->channel->item as $item){
    $strtemp = "<p><a href=\"$item->link\">"."$item->title</a> <span class=\"time\" style=\"font-size:11px;color:#555;\">".date("d.m.Y",strtotime($item->pubDate))."</span></p>\n";
    echo $strtemp;
    }
?>
```

Но, блин, выводит всё, что в ней есть. Порядка 25 штук.
А мне нужно выводить 1-2-3 записи. Т.е. указанное количество.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3):

убойный вопрос конечно))))

```
$i=0;
foreach ( $data as $k => $v ) {
 $i++;
if ($i == 3) break;
}
```

Comment: Увы, я не в теме.
Поэтому доп.коммент еще убойней.

А куда это вставить, чтобы работало?

Comment: а счетчик то зачем?)))))) foreach ( $data as $k => $v ) {if ($k == 2) break;} и усе)))

Comment: @mountpoint нюню)
$array = array( 'one' => 'value1', 'two' => 'value2' );

@bande не в теме чего? что делает Ваш код? Как только разберетесь -- поймете куда вставлять.

Comment: @thunder XML-ноды в переборе не имеют ассоциативных ключей

Comment: @dekameron тут да, тут счетчик можно не использовать, но и учить человека, что можно со счетчиком делать тож нужно :) Но вдруг захочется сделать ассоциативные ключи по датам? тогда без счетчика не получится :) Я в более глобальном стиле ессно это написал :)

Comment: нихрена не понял, что насоветовали.

но всем спасибо :D

Comment: круто-круто, охренеть, работает!!! ААААА!!! Я счастлив!!! АААА СПАСИБО!!!!

Comment: Ну отлично) Все же просто? :)

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте!
А вот в этом коде как вывести три последние новости? Использовать предложенный выше  способ у меня не получается, т.к. я - чайник. Спасибо.

```
введите сюда код
```

```html
<?php
   
$rss = simplexml_load_file ( 'http://sinfo-mp.ru/rss02.rss' );

echo '<table>'."\n";
foreach ( $rss->channel->item as $item ) 
{
  echo '<tr valign="top">';
  $image = $item->enclosure;
  
  echo '<td>';
  $tt = iconv  ("UTF-8", "windows-1251", "$item->title");
  echo '<li><b><a href="'.$item->link.'">'.$tt.'</a></b>';
  $st = iconv  ("UTF-8", "windows-1251", "$item->description");
  echo '<div>'.$st.'</div>';
  echo '<div><FONT size=1>'.$item->pubDate.'</FONT></div>';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '</tr>'."\n";
  echo '<tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>'."\n"; 
 }
echo '</table>';

?>
```